# Completely uninstall the subsystem for Linux on Win10?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was fooling around a bit with the Linux/Bash subsystem for Win10.

But then I decided to stay with Cygwin for now. So I uninstalled it - or thought I did.

Now I've installed Cygwin and put its `bin` directory first in the `PATH`.

In `cmd.exe` , when I type `bash` , it will start the Cygwin's Bash.

But when I do <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `bash`, I still get the prompt:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
…bla-bla-bla…
```

How do I get rid of the Linux/Bash subsystem entirely, so it will instead pick up Cygwin's Bash from the `PATH`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In order to disable WSL, one has to go back into

Control Panel -> programs-features -> turn on/off Windows features and deselect Windows Subsystem for Linux, and Save.

Comment: Note that this will remove all WSL installs.  If you just want to remove one (such as because you installed WSL 2 and want to remove WSL 1), use `wslconfig` as described here: https://superuser.com/a/1337814/605884.  For example, to uninstall the WSL 1 install, use `wslconfig /u Legacy`

Comment: This didn't work for me as the ticked checkbox was greyed out. Power-shell answer from Abraham did work however.

Comment: I unregistered Ubuntu, then turned off Windows Subsystem for Linux, rebooted and turned it on again. To my surprise Ubuntu was still there afterwards (the user I created was shown on the prompt of the Linux shell). How to remove the distribution completely?

Comment: What will happen with the distros on the filesysteme? Does disabling the window feature for WSL remove them completely?

Answer (score 65):

If your OS has been upgraded to the Fall Creators Update, you should be able to issue the command `wslconfig`.

You could of course try uninstalling first by using the command `lxrun /uninstall /full`.

If its still there, you can try unregistering the distro:

- First you need to know which distro is installed by using

  ```
  wslconfig /l
  ```
- From the list choose the distro (e.g. Ubuntu) you want to uninstall and type the command

  ```
  wslconfig /u Ubuntu
  ```

Comment: lxrun was deprecated with the release of 1709, and wslconfig doesn’t exist before it, this could be a decent answer if it was improved to be specific.  Author was using 1703 (or earlier) by the way.

Comment: Works as of Apr 2019.

Comment: I had to do a `wslconfig /u Legacy` to remove the Ubuntu that was shipped with Windows.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit - This would only work on Windows Server, not on Client OS.*

Similar to what Rop suggested, but you can also use Powershell to completely remove the Windows Subsystem for Linux, with the advantage of not having to look for it in Control Panel.  Note that you will have to run this as an administrator.

```
Remove-WindowsFeature Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

List all the features available, filtering for Linux:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object Name -like '*linux*' | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: FYI, OP asked for Win10; Remove-WindowsFeature doesn't work on client O/S

`PS C:\Windows\system32> Remove-WindowsFeature -Name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Remove-WindowsFeature : The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.`

Comment: @DarkMoon, thank you for pointing that out.  Edited to make that obvious to avoid causing heartache to anyone else.

Answer (score 4):

Just a few notes for experimenters, but for Windows 10 client o/s, you can use the following:

```
 (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName '*linux*') | Select-Object FeatureName
```

Then:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Or the analogue:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

You can use other tooling to the same affect, such as dism.exe (as illustrated here: https://evidencen.com/wsl2/)

Answer (score 2):

I combined removing Ubuntu-18.04

```
wslconfig /l 
wslconfig /u 'Ubuntu-18.04'
```

and with adding and launching Ubuntu-20.04 from the Windows store
to successfully get WSL 2.0 running again it stopped working. I was getting

```
[process exited with code 4294967295]
```

when I launched wsl 2.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10:

- search: "optional features" (-> manage optional features)
- second last entry on page: more windows features
- second last entry: WSL