# What can I safely delete in C:\Users\<MyUsername> ? At 22GB++ Is it too large?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-space

As per the title, is it too much to have a 22GB Users folder ?
What can I delete, help, I am getting annoyed :-)
[image]

Comment: `...is it too much to have a 22GB Users folder?` - only if you're out of storage space.  This is your "profile" folder.  Many (most) of the files relative to your user account are stored in this folder.  If you don't understand how this folder is structured it is best to read up on it and become familiar before making any changes.  If you need to free up storage space on your drive quickly do things like empty the temp folder, purge your downloads, look for things in Documents and Pictures that can go (back them up if needed), etc.

Comment: Do not delete anything out of App Data unless you are fully and completely familiar with what is in there. Otherwise you are faced with reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @squillman, Basically 4 folders Windows, Program Files (x86), Users, ProgramData are taking up 91% of my C: drive; [ I had already done what you said re Temp, Docs, Pics, etc prior to posting the question ]

Comment: Yes, that's not unusual.  Start with the folders I mentioned in my previous comment.  Again, unless you're familiar with what's in there you don't want to mess with this folder.

Comment: Best thing for you to do is change to a larger drive. 512GB is a practical minimum size today (2021, 2022, 2023)

Comment: to be more clear: NO, 22GB user folder is not an indication of anything and is not "too much" and is not of any consequence.

Comment: <rant> when SSDs were expensive, laptop manufacturers convinced many people that a 128GB SSD was "great". They were wrong, & quite probably intentionally misleading. The Users folder is not too large, you were fooled into buying a computer with a drive far too small. You really need a bigger drive. </rant>

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know if I was fooled or not, this is my NUC where I made the decision that 110GB was enough for Windows 7 on C drive and 1TB on D drive, and it has been functioning well as a Dev PC for a good few years now; but after every upgrade to Win 8 and then Win 10, the minimal diskspace requirements keep increasing.

Comment: I had a couple of PCs I put 128s in when they came out, as they were really expensive. They were too small for anything except just a boot drive. I replaced them all, smallest now is 512. They're just too limiting & every write makes you have to watch space. You can also wear them out in months if there's no space left - basically you're hammering writes onto a few spare GB. My first died in 6 months, the 2nd I recycled shortly after, before it could fail. I've a few 1TB SSDs still going strong at 8 or 9 years. I do blame the manufacturers for selling these to an unsuspecting general public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folders in your screenshot should not be manually deleted. You should instead clean up from within the related applications (or uninstall them). Some examples using your screenshot:

- **Packages** is where your WSL environment is saved. Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/1317883/673426) for how to remove/clean it up
- **Microsoft** usually contains Office stuff like Outlook mailbox/Teams temp data. It can also just be Edge temp storage, OneDrive, etc.
- **LINE** is temp data from the Line chat app. It can be cleared following the steps here: https://help.line.me/line/?contentId=20005079
- **Postman** looks like it can be deleted, but will remove all your local settings: https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410785125271-How-to-remove-local-data
- **Google** is just chrome temp data, and can be cleared at: [chrome://settings/clearBrowserData](https://chrome://settings/clearBrowserData)

Hope those help!

Comment: Someone should be awared an answer, and it may as well be you.